# Как использовать css в react?

Tags: reactjs

Пробовал найти и запустить какие-то проекты с GitHub, но ничего не работает. Постоянно всегда какие-то ошибки. В issues просто тупо закрывают твой вопрос.

Покажите нормальный пример, где это работает?

Пересмотрел все туториалы, но не работает оттуда тоже ничего!

Как же всё надоело. Какая-то жуткая костыльная и дурацкая технология этот react!

webpack.config.js:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/client.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: 'public/js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
                }
            },
            {   test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
    ]
};
```

Comment: Вы хотите писать css в jsx файлах?

Comment: Да, именно! Я хочу import css from './style.css' Но не работает! Все настройки по сто раз менял-переменял, но не получается нифига. Использую webpack.

Comment: Покажите настройки webpack для css

Comment: Закинул в пост. Эта одна из настроек, которая не работает. Я всё перепробовал. Дело в том, что во всяких туториалах показывают, как делать на обычном примере, или устаревших версиях. Но как только ты подключаешь всё вместе: jsx, server-rendering и т.д. Всё, всё рушится к чертям! Как с этим быть - никто не говорит!

Comment: т.е. файл `styles.css` у вас не появляется? У меня почти такой-же конфиг, только для `less` с добавленным одним лоадером. Не знаю что у вас может не работать. Может вы просто не подключаете к странице файл `styles.css`? **И react это не костыльная технология)**

Comment: Василий, файл собирается, но когда импортишь css, код не компилируется, babel его не понимает и ругается

Comment: Ну вот. Из-за Вебпака - Реакт отругали :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работает вот так

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './app/client.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: 'public/js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
                }
            },
            {   test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                  fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
                  loader: "css-loader",
                }),
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
    ]
};
```

Также версий:

```
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
"css-loader": "^0.26.4",
"style-loader": "^0.13.2",
"webpack": "^2.2.1"
```

Если будут ошибки то напишите.

---

Проблема в файле `server.js`
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1754#issuecomment-186856033

Comment: Сам файл через webpack собирается. Но я не могу запустить проект, так как babel не может обработать css. И ещё - у меня server-side rendering.

Comment: Но на выходе вам webpack дает css файл?

Comment: Да, даёт. Но css он не может скомпилировать теперь. Если убрать, то нормально компилирует.

Comment: вы так например подключаете css в js: import  './style.css';?

Comment: так: import css from './header.css' и так: import './header.css' - не принимает.

Comment: если так import css from './header.css'  делаете то какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: SyntaxError: C:/site.dev/site-spa/react/app/components/Header/header.css: Unexpected token, expected ; (1:5)
> 1 | body {
    |      ^
  2 |     background-color: #2d4469;
  3 |     color: white;
  4 |     font-size: 20px;

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55048/discussion-between-qpeela-and-daryn-k).

Comment: Ответил в чат, ничего не работает

Answer (score 0):

Покажите нормальный пример, где это работает?

Вся структура папок проекта, доступна здесь : https://bitbucket.org/stasok/react-complete/src/fd861f5bb714/boilerplate-3/?at=master

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple react app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "Andrew Mead",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.9.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "expect": "^1.14.0",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.2.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "script-loader": "^0.6.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'script!foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js',
    './app/app.jsx'
  ],
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      '$': 'jquery',
      'jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    alias: {
      applicationStyles: 'app/styles/app.scss'
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
      },
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
    }]
  },
  sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/foundation-sites/scss')
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
};
```

**server.js**

```js
var express = require('express');

// Create our app
var app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https') {
    res.redirect('http://' + req.hostname + req.url);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('Express server is up on port ' + PORT);
});
```

Comment: Скачал, посмотрел. Ужасный и нагроможденный подход. Мне надо подключать стили в компонентах. и потом, чтобы всё собиралось в один style.css. Файл собирается, но когда делаешь import css-файла, код не компилируется, ругается, что не понимает css.

Comment: @DarynK вы boilerplate-3 - использовали ? у меня ничего такого нет. импортирую css все компилируется